# Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011

Tags: objective-c, json, serialization, twitter, afnetworking

I want to use twitter API and I have an error. I have a button and I want to see tweets when I click the button.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)transmit:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *myString =@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=-22.912214,-43.230182,1km&lang=pt&result_type=recent";
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:myString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:myString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"data: %@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

and it says that error :

```
2016-07-19 16:39:51.472 JSON[1377:77302] Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fdb1b607c00> { URL: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=-22.912214,-43.230182,1km&lang=pt&result_type=recent } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 87;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 19 Jul 2016 13:39:51 GMT";
    Server = "tsa_a";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=631138519";
    "x-connection-hash" = 60ae6b2848e6b6cc27045899a9487783;
    "x-response-time" = 3;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=(TWITTER LINKS I CAN NOT WRITE IT BECAUSE OF MY REPUTATION) =<7b226572 726f7273 223a5b7b 22636f64 65223a32 31352c22 6d657373 61676522 3a224261 64204175 7468656e 74696361 74696f6e 20646174 612e227d 5d7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}
```

I searched but I couldn't solve this problem. what should i do to fix it?

Comment: Try to use this, NSString *string = [myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Where should I add this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change transmit function with this code .

```
- (IBAction)transmit:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *myString =@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=-22.912214,-43.230182,1km&lang=pt&result_type=recent";
 NSString *Path = [myString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:Path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
}
```